# Using Databricks to convert Excel to a standard format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-data-lake, databricks

I'm trying to implement a process using Data Factory and Databricks to ingest data into Data Lake and convert it all to a standard format i.e. parquet. So we'll have a raw data tier and a clean/standardized data tier.

When the source system is a DB or delimited files its (relatively) easy, but in some cases we will have excel sources. I've been testing the conversion process with `com.crealytics.spark.excel` which is ok because we can infer the schema BUT its not able to iterate through multiple sheets OR get the list of sheet names to enable me to iterate thought each one to convert into a single file.

I need this to be as dynamic as possible so that we can ingest almost any file regardless or its type or schema.

Does anyone know of any alternative methods of doing this? I'm open to moving away from databricks if necessary, such as Azure Batch with a custom C# script.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are aiming to store the data in Azure Data Lake, another approach may be to use Azure Data Lake Analytics with a custom Excel extractor. U-SQL then can convert it into Parquet. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/tree/master/Samples/ExcelExtractor) for a sample Excel extractor.

How much variability do you expect with the Excel sheets?

The main problem here will be that it is hard to be completely schema agnostic, especially if you have many columns. To handle variability of the schema, you could change the extractor to output the columns either as key/value pairs or - if the number of columns and size of a row is reasonable - as a `SqlMap` (or a few for different target types). Although you would have to probably pivot it into a column format before creating the Parquet which would either require a second script to create the pivoting script or some custom outputter (instead of the built-in Parquet outputter).